# BS4 not displaying text in Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm learning Python(Flask) and BeautifulSoup. For my first project I just wanted to wanted to get a video name from YT and display it on the homepage of my web app.

An error returns:
***AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'***

```
import requests
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)


def scrapper():
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
    web_response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_response, 'lxml')

    card = soup.find(class_='style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media').text
    return card


@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', text=scrapper())
```

Comment: it seems that `soup` cant find 'style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media'. what is the video name that you want?

Comment: @JayPeerachai It's just a random video (first video) from the homepage. I've tried getting the id = 'video-title'  to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Beautifulsoup` can capture only static HTML source code. YT contains the `javascript` content which is code that runs on the client. Use a tool that can handle `javascript`, such as, `selenium`.

for example,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'

# your path for selenium driver (e.g., chrome or firefox)
webdriverFile = your_path + '/geckodriver' # gecko for firefox
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=webdriverFile)
browser.get(url)
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
browser.close()

for i in soup.find_all("yt-formatted-string", {"id": "video-title"}):
    print(i.text)
```

output:

```
> Music for Healing Stress, Anxiety and Depression, Remove Inner Rage and Sadness
> รวมเพลงฮิตในติ๊กต๊อก ( ผีเห็นผี + ไทม์แมชชิน ) เพลงมาแรงฟังกันยาวๆ2022
> เพลงเพราะในTikTok ครูหนุ่มแจง ไม่ได้เทงานแต่ง ยันเลิกกันด้วยดี
> Smooth Jazz Music & Bossa Nova For Good Mood - Positive Jazz Lounge Cafe Music, Coffee Shop BGM
> เปิดห้องทำงานใหม่ที่บ้าน — บอกหมด จัดห้อง จัดโต๊ะ จัดไฟ ใช้ของอะไรบ้าง
> Boyce Avenue Greatest Hits Full Album 2021 - Best Songs Of Boyce
> Avenue 2021  - Acoustic songs 2021
> .....
```